# Design a MOD-N counter using LS293 circuits

Tags: digital-logic, counter

This is the internal scheme of the LS293 circuit.
[image]
I understand that the CP0 frequency will be divided by 2 and the CP1 will be divided by 8, but I don't understand how to use this circuit to build a mod-n counter.

Comment: as far as I see, it is a 4-bit up counter. I think one of the pins should be an asynchronous reset for the counter. Assume you want a mod 7 counter, the highest possible number is 6 in base 7. 6 is 0110 and 7 is 0111 in binary. So, you should connect a signal which will be 1(or 0, depending on active low or active high reset pin) only when the number becomes 0111 which is 7. When it becomes 7, at right that instance, the counter will be reset to 0 and continue counting from there.

Comment: @muyustan so basically when Q2, Q1, Q0 are HIGH(in the example with the mod 7 counter), both MR1 and MR2 should be HIGH in order to reset Q2, Q1, and Q0

Comment: no, it might be unsafe to say Q2*Q1*Q0 directly, we also have Q3'. It may not create a problem if everything goes smooth, but there is a possibility. So better is to avoid it. So, your counter should reset when `Q3'&Q2&Q1&Q0` is 0(it looks like active low reset pin). NAND gate will output 0 only when both inputs are 1. So arrange it accordingly. (MR1 = Q3'&Q2 and MR2 = Q1&Q0 looks like valid solution)

Comment: @muyustan thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have access to the reset pin. exploit that, as part of state transition table